# Valueerror numpy.poly1d()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a simple array which is the result of `numpy.linalg.solve`. I use it to create a polynom using numpy.poly1d(). No matter what I try: numpy.asarray(), numpy.reshape(), numpy.transpose() etc. I get this error:

```
[[ 1.         -0.99390328  0.1617277 ]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aPCv1.py", line 62, in <module>
    p = np.poly1d(c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 1094, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Polynomial must be 1d only.")
ValueError: Polynomial must be 1d only.
```

where `c = [[ 1.         -0.99390328  0.1617277 ]]` is the terminal output of my array with the coefficients.

Comment: why are your coefficients wrapped inside a second list? Try your code with `c = [1.0, -0.994, 0.162]` instead of `[[ ... ]]`. If this is the common output of the `linalg.solve` funtion, try `numpy.poly1d(c[0])` to address the list inside your list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to reduce the dimensions of c by 1. This can be done by numpy using :

`c = np.squeeze(c)`

or by extracting the first item:

`c=c[0]`

or using a list comprehension:

`c = [i for i in j for j in c]`